# Resharper conver to LINQ bug? Or is my code wrong

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I have this method

```
 public static Status BiggestOverdue(List<StatusOverdueMinutes> overdueMinutes, DateTime lastReceived, int receiveTimeSpanMinutes)
 {
     var maxMinutesOverdueFound = 0;
     var status = Status.Ok;

     if (lastReceived.AddMinutes(receiveTimeSpanMinutes) >= DateTime.Now || 
         receiveTimeSpanMinutes == -1)
                return Status.Ok;

     foreach (var overdueStatus in overdueMinutes.Where(overdueStatus => 
              lastReceived.AddMinutes(receiveTimeSpanMinutes + 
              overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes) < DateTime.Now))
        if (overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes > maxMinutesOverdueFound)
        {
            maxMinutesOverdueFound = overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes;
            status = overdueStatus.StatusId;
        }

    return status;
}
```

**Status enum**

```
public enum Status
{
    Error = 0,
    Warning = 1,
    Information = 2,
    Ok = 3,
    NeedsConfig = 4,
    Maintenance = 5,
    Disabled = 6,
    Enabled = 7
}
```

I have unit tests backing up that it works as I expect it to (i.e. it returns from the list the status that is most overdue)

```
public void ShouldReturnError()
{
    var lastReceived = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
    var overdueMinutes = new List<StatusOverdueMinutes>
    {
        new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 10, StatusId = Status.Error},
        new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 7, StatusId = Status.Warning},
        new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 5, StatusId = Status.Information}
    };
    const int receiveTimeSpan = 15;
    var status = CacheHelper.BiggestOverdue(overdueMinutes, lastReceived, receiveTimeSpan);
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.Error, status);
}
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldReturnWarning()
{
    var lastReceived = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
    var overdueMinutes = new List<StatusOverdueMinutes>
                         {
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 20, StatusId = Status.Error},
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 7, StatusId = Status.Warning},
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 5, StatusId = Status.Information}
                         };
    const int receiveTimeSpan = 15;
    var status = CacheHelper.BiggestOverdue(overdueMinutes, lastReceived, receiveTimeSpan);
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.Warning, status);
}
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldReturnInformation()
{
    var lastReceived = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
    var overdueMinutes = new List<StatusOverdueMinutes>
                         {
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 30, StatusId = Status.Error},
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 27, StatusId = Status.Warning},
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 10, StatusId = Status.Information}
                         };
    const int receiveTimeSpan = 15;
    var status = CacheHelper.BiggestOverdue(overdueMinutes, lastReceived, receiveTimeSpan);
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.Information, status);
}
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldReturnOk()
{
    var lastReceived = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
    var overdueMinutes = new List<StatusOverdueMinutes>
                         {
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 20, StatusId = Status.Error},
                             new StatusOverdueMinutes {OverdueMinutes = 15, StatusId = Status.Warning},
                         };
    const int receiveTimeSpan = 15;
    var status = CacheHelper.BiggestOverdue(overdueMinutes, lastReceived, receiveTimeSpan);
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.Ok, status);
}
```

Resharper suggests that a portion of the loop body can be converted to linq. This is what it proposes:

```
        foreach (var overdueStatus in overdueMinutes.Where(overdueStatus => lastReceived.AddMinutes(receiveTimeSpanMinutes + overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes) < DateTime.Now)
                                                    .Where(overdueStatus => overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes > maxMinutesOverdueFound))
        {
            maxMinutesOverdueFound = overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes;
            status = overdueStatus.StatusId;
        }
```

As a result it says this line:

```
maxMinutesOverdueFound = overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes;
```

Value assigned is not used in any execution path and it can be removed. So i remove it. This makes my loop body this:

```
foreach (var overdueStatus in overdueMinutes.Where(overdueStatus => lastReceived.AddMinutes(receiveTimeSpanMinutes + overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes) < DateTime.Now)
                                  .Where(overdueStatus => overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes > maxMinutesOverdueFound))
            {
                status = overdueStatus.StatusId;
            }
```

And now my tests fail. Is this a bug in resharper? Or am I doing something completely stupid here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, resharper hasn't understood your code and suggests something wrong. You need `maxMinutesOverdueFound` to find the max value and you update this value in the `if` consecutively:

```
if (overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes > maxMinutesOverdueFound)
{
    maxMinutesOverdueFound = overdueStatus.OverdueMinutes;
    status = overdueStatus.StatusId;
}
```

If resharper now tries to remove this `if` and only compares with the inital value it is not correct.

So the LINQ conversion resharper suggests is incorrect even if you would update the value in the foreach because the `Where` filtered only by the initial value.

But you can simplify the whole query to this, no `foreach` or tracking variable needed:

```
StatusOverdueMinutes maxOverdueStatus = overdueMinutes
    .Where(odm => lastReceived.AddMinutes(receiveTimeSpanMinutes + odm.OverdueMinutes) < DateTime.Now)
    .OrderByDescending(odm => odm.OverdueMinutes)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (maxOverdueStatus == null) return Status.Ok;
return maxOverdueStatus.StatusId;
```